# php and html - By pressing a button, how to be redirected to a another page and in the same time triggers a php file

Tags: php, html

I have a php page wich has a button (index.php), and this php page contains variables and I want to use them in another php script(script.php) in another file but at the same time, I want the user to be redirected to an html page (success.html)
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `<form action="script.php" method="post">` in index.php and put this line of code at the end of your script in script.php:

```
header('location: 'success.html']);
```

How are you passing your variables to script.php?

If you put this script in script.php:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $$key=$value;
        }
```

Then it will create variables for all of your form elements with a `name=""` atribute, and assign them their respective values.

Example:

`<input type="text" name="firstname" value="John">`

will create the variable

`$firstname = 'John';`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple there are several ways of doing this, you can use sessions or set a form to posts the results.  So on index.php you could do something like this

```
<?php

 session_start()
 $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
 header("location:success.html");

?>
```

you now have global access to $_SESSION['foo'];

```
<?php 
   echo $_SESSION['foo']; // will output bar
```

Comment: what is sessioon foo?? sorry, I only know the basics of php :s

Comment: No problem. Foo just identifies the session variable. You could use anything you like. $_SESSION['anything']. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp